# EF5 Code First Automatic Migrations to Azure Database

Tags: sql, entity-framework, azure, entity-framework-migrations

I posted a more detailed question about this but am not getting many responses.  So, in the simplest terms, has anyone successfully set up automatic migrations on an Azure database using EF 5.0 Code First?  Please respond if you have and we can go from there.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I have managed to set it up, and it definitely works. 
You can refer to a [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16543229/publish-entity-framework-code-first-migrations-with-no-context-in-the-startup-pr) to see a problem I had.